# How to automate changing certain types of usernames to find accounts containing e-mail address? (Powershell [Enums])

Tags: powershell, email, replace, enums, active-directory

I have to check the password validity of admin users in my office. If a user's password is about to expire it should automatically send an email to said user.

All of that wouldn't be a problem if those user accounts had their corresponding email addresses saved in their properties but they don't.

They are instead saved in user accounts who are named the same except for the first three letters. So I need to change the usernames like this:

```
    if ($user.samaccountname -like 'sam*') {
            $newusername = $user.SamAccountName -replace 'sam', 'pel'
            $newuser = Get-ADUser -Filter {Name -eq $newusername} -Properties *
            $sendmailto = $newuser.email
    }
    elseif ($user.samaccountname -like 'exa*') {
            $newusername = $user.SamAccountName -replace 'exa', 'mpl'
            $newuser = Get-ADUser -Filter {Name -eq $newusername} -Properties *
            $sendmailto = $newuser.email
    }
```

etc.

Is there any better or smarter way to do this? I was told I could/should use enumerations but I don't see any sense in doing that for my script..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are doing something similar as in my work environment.
try using something like this.

```
cls
$ErrorActionPreference = "stop"
$VerbosePreference = "Continue"

$TimeSpan = (Get-Date).adddays(-80)
$PreFixArray = @("sup", "adm") #add more with ,"xxxx" can be different in lenght to.

$Regex = ("^($($PreFixArray -join '|'))") 
$Filter = ($PreFixArray | % { "pwdLastSet -le $($TimeSpan.ToFileTime()) -and samaccountname -like `"$_*`"" }) -Join ' -or '

$ExpiringAdmins = Get-ADUser -Properties Passwordlastset, pwdLastSet -filter $Filter

Foreach ($ExpiringAdmin in $ExpiringAdmins) {    
    $mailaddress = $null
    Try {
        $mailaddress = (Get-ADUser -Identity (($ExpiringAdmin.SamAccountName) -replace $regex, "usr") -Properties mail).mail
    } 

    Catch [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFoundException] {
        Write-Warning "Could not find a matching user for $($ExpiringAdmin.name), skipping"
    }

    Catch {
        Write-Warning "An unkown error ocured for $($ExpiringAdmin.name), skipping"
        continue #goes to the next $ExpiringAdmin in the ForEach Loop.
    }

    if ((!$mailaddress) -or ($mailaddress -eq "")) {$mailaddress = "EMAIL_NOT_FOUND"}
    Write-Verbose "$($ExpiringAdmin.samaccountname) is of type $(if($ExpiringAdmin.Name -match $Regex){$Matches[1]}) and the mail is : $($mailaddress)"
}
```

Comment: If I understood correctly, this just removes the first three letters of the string, correct?

Our cases are indeed similar but we differ at something, as the "normal" user doesn't just have no letters before the shortname but different letters than those of the admin account.

So: admjdoe ==> admin account & usrjdoe & "normal" account

Do you know something similar replacing the first three with something?

Besides that, do you have any Idea about why I was told to use enums for this?

Comment: Ah i see, will update the code to include a replace then.

About the question, i dont now much about enums and i dont now why someone would suggested using them in this situation i believe the code is fast and simple enough as it is right now but correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much! Yeah I can't see myself using enums for something like this either.

Comment: @T.Cruz, made a small adjustment to the AD filter this is dynamic to now.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using exchange? you can try to look for the emailadress based on SamAccountName within exhange

Comment: There are no email addresses behind those accounts, that's exactly my problem